# After upgrading to angular 5 webpack command is failing

Tags: angular, visual-studio, webpack, asp.net-core, angular5

My project was running on dot net core 2.0 with angular 4.2.
I update it to latest angular (5.0.0).
Since then, exception is thrown at this line in a startup.cs Configure method.

```
 app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
 {
     HotModuleReplacement = true
 });
```

Fails here with error

```
Error: Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. 
Current version is "5.0.0".
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Personal\Code\PettlyUi\PettlyUi\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:27:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
```

The Same error is thrown when I use webpack from the command line too.

I tried the same with new projects also and it consistently fails. Is this some kind of bug or I have not updated properly.

Command used for upgrading:

```
npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest 
@angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest 
@angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-
browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest 
@angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest
```

Comment: what is the version of `angular-cli` which is installed globally? use the command `ng -v` and update the post

Comment: cli version was 1.5, 
However I solved my problem finally after hours of struggle,
this command saved me,
npm install --save-dev @ngtools/webpack@latest
looks like ngtools/webpack needed to be updated.

what I was trying earlier is just this,
npm install --save webpack@latest

Sorry for the trouble guys

Comment: but I still have a doubt around the error message "needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "5.0.0".", 
does it qualify as a bug

Comment: No. Are you available in TeamViewer?.

Comment: cant as it is official code, but can you please suggest how it can be justified

Comment: uninstall all the node_modules from global and local folder and clean the cache install fresh set and try

Comment: no that doesn't help, nd anyways I fixed the issue, my concern now is why it says needs greater than 2.3.1 and current version is 5.0.0. even though 5.0.0 is greater than 2.3.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158219/discussion-between-aravind-and-code-name-jack).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since there are no answers, I will write what fixed my problem

This issue may occur because Angular is updated to version 5.0.0 but **ngtools** is still older. This causes webpack command to fail. Use this command to update webpack to latest,

```
npm install --save-dev @ngtools/webpack@latest
```

The error incorrectly tries to point to old compiler-cli version, which is clearly not the case.