# Update to angular 5 throws Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is 5.1.0

Tags: angular

I want to upgrade angular 4 from asp.net core2 to angular 5 (latest one)

I did this steps:

1. dotnet new angular
2. > npm install @angular/animations@latest @angular/common@latest 
   >   @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest 
   >   @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest 
   >   @angular/platform-browser@latest 
   >   @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest 
   >   @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest rxjs@latest
   >   --save
   >   npm install typescript@2.4.2 --save-exact
3. npm install (to make sure)
4. dotnet run

and it produce error : (Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "5.1.0".)
and i have no idea how to fix it.

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.5",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  }
}
```

here is the exception errors that produced:

> Using launch settings from
>   f:\temp\WebAppLinkSys\MyApp\MyApp\Properties\launchSettings.json...
>   info:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
>         User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\adwin\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key
>   repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest. Application
>   startup exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. (Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or
>   greater. Current version is "5.1.0". Error: Version of
>   @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is
>   "5.1.0".
>       at Object. (f:\temp\WebAppLinkSys\MyApp\MyApp\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:27:11)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object. (f:\temp\WebAppLinkSys\MyApp\MyApp\webpack.config.js:4:19)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)) ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException:
>   Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current
>   version is "5.1.0".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: Upgrading to version 5 error: Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "5.0.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244150/angular-upgrading-to-version-5-error-version-of-angular-compiler-cli-needs-to)

Comment: I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104188/migrating-angular-4-x-to-angular-5 this solution but not working. still producing the same erorr

Comment: This is completely unrelated to ASP.NET Core and c#. Please only tag relevant tags.

Comment: found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47105660/after-upgrading-to-angular-5-webpack-command-is-failing 

by upgrading the webpack 
npm install --save-dev @ngtools/webpack@latest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After upgrading to angular 5 webpack command is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47105660/after-upgrading-to-angular-5-webpack-command-is-failing)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

found the answer 
[After upgrading to angular 5 webpack command is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47105660/after-upgrading-to-angular-5-webpack-command-is-failing)

npm install --save-dev @ngtools/webpack@latest