# Angular components are removed after installing a new component

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core web application with angular 5. I want to generate some Barcodes and let the user to print them. After searching I found [ngx-barcode](https://yobryon.github.io/ngx-barcode/). A barcode component for Angular4+. As it says in its page I need install it using this command

```
$ npm install ngx-barcode –save
```

So at the node.js command prompt I run that command in my application directory. Like this:

```
E:\MyprojectDir\ npm install ngx-barcode –save
```

After getting some warning and at the end of the command execution I got the following message in command prompt:

> Added 2 packages and removed 21 packages.

It seems it has been deleted all other node packages from my project.  And now there are no reference to angular/core, angular/forms and others package in my project.

This is the content of my package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng", 
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "postinstall": "webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
        "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
        "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
        "karma": "~1.7.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
        "tslint": "~5.7.0",
        "typescript": "~2.4.2",
        "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
        "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
        "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
        "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
        "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
        "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
        "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
        "css": "2.2.1",
        "css-loader": "0.28.4",
        "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
        "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
        "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
        "file-loader": "0.11.2",
        "html-loader": "0.4.5",
        "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
        "jquery": "3.2.1",
        "json-loader": "0.5.4",
        "preboot": "4.5.2",
        "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
        "rxjs": "5.4.2",
        "style-loader": "0.18.2",
        "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
        "url-loader": "0.5.9",
        "webpack": "2.5.1",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
        "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
        "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
        "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
        "karma": "~1.7.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
        "tslint": "~5.7.0",
        "typescript": "~2.4.2",
        "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
        "chai": "4.0.2",
        "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
        "karma-webpack": "2.0.3"
    }
}
```

It's so nice of you to help me.

Comment: What npm installs and uninstalls depends entirely on your package.json file. What does it contain?

Comment: It contains a hundred lines. could you please tell what should I write inside it to prevent removing existing packages?

Comment: a hundred lines? That's a lot!. But anyway, just post it.

Comment: I edit my question and append the content of my package.

Comment: ```npm i``` will be help.

Comment: I don't know how this file ended up like this, but it's messed up: all your dependencies have been replaced by the dev dependencies. Look into your git history to get back the correct file, or simply recreate an angular project from scratch, and use the package.json that the CLI generates.

Comment: The file is generated automatically by asp.net core spa template. any way thanks @JBNizet for your time.

Comment: @fatemefazli thanks. It solved my problem. after running the command I got this error "Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "5.1.0". that it was solved too by using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47762846/update-to-angular-5-throws-version-of-angular-compiler-cli-needs-to-be-2-3-1-or?rq=1. Anyway if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @VahidGhadiri your welcome Vahid. in this type of errors always ```npm install``` again will give us a good clue where the main problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this type of errors always `npm install` again will give us a good clue where the main problem is. 
and based on @VahidGhadiri mentioned ,next step:

```
npm install --save-dev @ngtools/webpack@latest
```

for resolving

> error "Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater.
>   Current version is "5.1.0"