# Error thrown during publishing dotnet core app

Tags: angular, angular-compiler-cli

I'm trying to publish a dotnet core 2.2 app with angular.

During the publishing I get following error:

```
Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "7.2.15"
```

I've tried to fix the version, running npm install and npm update. But honestly speaking I don't understand what is the problem.

I've tried to publish with following command:

```sh
dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64
```

Publish works without error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update webpack. It solves this issue

npm install --save-dev @ngtools/webpack@latest

I had similer issue with .net core. This link helped me

[Update to angular 5 throws Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is 5.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47762846/update-to-angular-5-throws-version-of-angular-compiler-cli-needs-to-be-2-3-1-or)

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on why this solve the issue? How have you obtained such information? Is there an official discussion which explains it?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to follow your suggestion, but with this fix I got following error "Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc'". Trying to fix that leads to more and more needed peer dependencies to install by myself.